# Why doesn't Defender get suspicious if a program adds exceptions to the Defender?

Tags: windows, virus, antivirus, trojan

One can simply add exceptions to the Windows Defender by running this command in Powershell:

```
Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath <your_path>
```

Why does Windows Defender not immediately flag programs that run such commands? Most processes that do this should have malicious intentions, right?

Malware authors can simply code an installer that adds a folder to the WinDef Exceptions and then download the malicious payloads into those folders and execute them, right?

Somehow seems too simple for me.

Comment: This command requires sufficient authorization to be executed.